# What is the aspect ratio of T-tail for common twin turboprops?

Tags: aircraft-design, t-tail

I'm trying to figure out typical AR values for a T-tail configuration (at the conseptual design phase). Working with Raymer I found this table:

[image]

I can see the typical AR values for the vertical tail but I cant find anything about the horizontal one. The only info that I got is that it should be lower than wing's AR. The aircraft that I'm interested about is a twin turboprop.

Comment: I'm not sure if [JAWA](https://shop.janes.com/Yearbooks-IHS/All-the-World-s-Aircraft/) has tail-aspect ratios. You could also find planform images of the aircraft you have in mind and calculate the aspect ratios. [Here's a list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:T-tail_aircraft) of T-tail aircraft

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmmm.

[image]
[[Source]](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=http%3A%2F%2Feurec4a.eu%2Findex.php%3Fid%3D5156&psig=AOvVaw12ln0j1hqiX4StmRZ1gbtI&ust=1593795744777000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAkQjhxqFwoTCOikiuCCr-oCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAD)
[image]

ATR42=6:1

[image]
[[Source]](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.modelflying.co.uk%2Fforums%2Fpostings.asp%3Fth%3D98163&psig=AOvVaw0tBMtP2p3gR58XNs1mZvzr&ust=1593796435052000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=2ahUKEwjo1I7EiK_qAhXLIrcAHarFDXsQr4kDegUIARCuAQ)
[image]

Dash8Q400=4:1

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any reason why the aspect ratio of the horizontal stabilizer of a T-tail needs to be any different than that of a conventional tail. I always interpreted the dash in Raymer to mean that the h-stab should be sized similarly in T-Tail as in a conventional. Apparently [this source](https://www.fzt.haw-hamburg.de/pers/Scholz/HOOU/AircraftDesign_9_EmpennageGeneralDesign.pdf) shares my interpretation.

Due to the end-plating effect, the vertical tail in a T-tail is more aerodynamically effective, resulting in generally shorter v-stab. However, for the same surface area, T-tail would have a heavier structure to cater for uneven load cases on the h-stab and the need for a bullet fairing.